# Mean of differnt combinations in a list (missing some of the combinations)

Tags: r, list, lapply

I have a list with two elements, where I have a variable of interest `value` for each combination of variables `country` and `gender`.

```
# Toy example
A <- list()
  
A[[1]] <- data.frame(country=c("Spain", "Spain", "France", "France"),
                       gender= c("M", "F", "M", "F"),
                       value = c(100,125,10,200))

A[[2]] <- data.frame(country=c("Spain", "Spain", "France"),
                       gender=c("M", "F", "F"),
                       value = c(150,75,100))
```

Data looks like this:

```
[[1]]
  country gender value
1   Spain      M   100
2   Spain      F   125
3  France      M    10
4  France      F   200

[[2]]
  country gender value
1   Spain      M   150
2   Spain      F    75
3  France      F   100
```

I would like to compute the mean of `value` (across the elements of the list) for each possible combination of `gender` and `country` taking into account that no all the combinations are in all the elements of the list (in that example, the second element has not a value for Males in France.

What I expect is something like this:

```
  country gender value
1   Spain      M   125
2   Spain      F   100
3  France      M     5
4  France      F   150
```

Any idea how to deal with that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
A %>%
  bind_rows() %>%
  group_by(country, gender) %>%
  summarise(value = sum(value) / length(A))
```

Comment: It works, but there is an incompatibility with `plyr` package. The first time I run the code it worked, but after loading that library, it didn't work. So, be careful with that.

Comment: Do not use `{plyr}` package..

Comment: @R18, as Mossa states, do not use plyr. The reason is not cause of this particular conflict, however it is a retired package without any updates for a long time. Use tidyverse or just dplyr instead. The key in solving your issue is to simply bind the rows and instead of using mean, use the sum and as per definition you want the missing rows in any of the tables be 0, so you can divide that by the amount of tables in your list.

Answer (score 1):

What you need here is `complete` from `{tidyr}`.

```r
A %>% 
  map(tidyr::complete, country, 
      gender = c("M", "F"), fill = list(value = 0)) %>% 
  bind_rows() %>% 
  group_by(country, gender) %>% 
  summarise(value = mean(value)) %>% 
  ungroup()
```

First the `map`, ensures that each list has all the rows for `M` and `F` for `gender`, and then complete with the present countries (you can also specify the countries that should be present). Then ensures that `NA` is `0` instead.

Comment: Thank you @Mossa! Although your proposal works for the example I wrote, It can be tricky when all the possible combinations depend on multiple variables, because as far as I understood we have tor write all the values they can take.

Comment: I show two uses with complete. Either you list all the values that they should attain, or you do nothing, and it will take the present combinations in the dataset. I usually list the combinations that are "finite", like `sex`, and for stuff that is more open-ended, I think using the present values is good enough.